# When should I use a service bus in asp.net websites?

Tags: asp.net, distributed, nservicebus, servicebus

I'm thinking of distributed website, where a website (Multi-instance) is backed by an App Server (Multi-instance). 
I'm struggling with defining the communication mechanism between these. I see a lot of options like WCF, messaging service, or as many would suggest by simply eliminating the App Server altogether.

So what would you do for Global Level websites which expects millions of visitors.

Okay, so these are lots of questions, but they are somehow related. Does a service bus help in scalable distributed sites ... or I'm mixing the words over here.

Any guidance is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this depends on the direction and importance of the communication.  It some cases you will have two way communication that will require typical request/response transports(HTTP, etc.).  In some cases you'll be able to use one way communication.  This would open you up to using a messaging transport, and supplying the ability to move some processing "offline".  This could help you scale the site, but you may just move your problems somewhere else without some careful design.

Importance matters because if you have some information from the user you don't want to lose, say orders, then that may also push you towards something more durable like messaging.  You don't necessarily need a Service Bus to use one way, durable communication, but the feature set provided may make things easier.

Comment: So you recommend an app server to scale up websites, but you don't strictly recommend a service bus as the exclusive or preferred communication way ... did I hear you well ?

Comment: The recommendation would depend on the type of system, is it a high read or write system, can the data be lost etc.  Pushing processing offline will typically help, and yes you don't need a full service bus.

Answer (score 2):

Also if you want to do load distribution or routing and filtering of the messages then you can use Topics/Subscriptions in Service Bus:  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Multi-Tier-application-6c033cad

Comment: Welcome to SO, really appreciate your answer
So a service bus is only preferred for durability and temporal decoupling of different pieces of the system... it isn't the best communication medium when it comes to querying read-only information

Comment: For read-only information where you want multiple reads of the same info, a messaging system like Service Bus Queues/Topics is not the right fit. Its best for messaging, communicating state/workload and request/response type scenarios. Messaging can be one-way too but those mostly fall under the event-publishing category.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which Service Bus can help with your scenario. As Adam mentions if you need durability and temporal decoupling then using a Service Bus durable Queue is a good option, some detailed guidance for that is here http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/multi-tier-application/

On the other hand if you have the application server sitting behind a firewall and just need NAT/Firewall traversal with full duplex communication then you can use Service Bus Relay to achieve that: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/hybrid-solution/